# PhantomJS Web Scraping Cisco Switch Web Interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs

I recently got into PhantomJS Currently using PhantomJS for my first developer job.

I've been tasked to web scrape network switch information (hostname, productID, IPaddress, MAC address, etc) from an old Cisco catalyst 2960 x switch connected to PC via LAN cable.

I got the http authenticatiion working fine with phantomJS headless browser and can open the first switch page but it leads to a startup page as seen in the image below.[cisco switch startup report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t07dW.jpg)

This startup page only appears for first time login/access to the switch after witch user must click the continue button which has the form button input property shown  below. (written in AJAX by the way)

```
<form METHOD="GET">
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Continue" 
onclick="setcookiesandLoadCiscoDeviceManager()"></form>
```

Usually on Chrome browser we click on it and move on. Which subsequently brings us to a the main page of interest, the Cisco Device Manager Page containing the Switch Information.(not allowed to post picture but it is available on the phantomjs group discussion page)

My question is, **to bypass the startup report with phantomJS headless browser what is best approach? Either...**

- Simulate button press on the form submission Method GET above triggering the link to go to the next page ($.ajax() comes to mind) or...
- Call the function setcookiesandLoadCiscoDeviceManager() through the .js file (more on that latter). This is more of a hacking approach.

The architecture of the switch web pages are outlined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYn47.png)

When the URL 10.44.39.252 is first requested 3 frame src are called. I know this  through the phantomjs callback

```
page.onNavigationRequested
```

- Frmwrkresource.htm
- topbannernofpv.shtml
- setup_report.htm

input "button1" exists inside setup_report.htm frame. When "button1" is pressed

```
setscookiesandLoadsCiscoDeviceManager();
```

is called

this function call exists only in preflight.js among all the javascript resources that are called transitioning between startup_report and the Cisco device manager(10.44.39.252/xhome.htm). I'm Thinking browser cookies is a major part of this problem.

attached is my source code. It is at various levels of completeion

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

console.log("\n:Welcome to my Crawler Scrapper:");

var url = 'http://10.44.39.252/';

page.settings.userName='star';
page.settings.password='----------';
page.customHeaders={'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('star:xzsawq4321')};

page.settings.userAgent = 'PMG Web Crawler Bot/1.0';

page.onNavigationRequested = function(url,type,willNavigate, main){
console.log("\n----------------------------------------------");
console.log("Navigation Request Information:\n")
console.log('Trying to navigate to: ' + url);//where are you going?
console.log('Caused by: ' + type);           //request type
console.log('Will it actually navigate: ' + willNavigate);
console.log('Sent from the page\'s main frame: ' + main);
console.log("----------------------------------------------\n");
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError){
console.log("\nHold Up, We have Errors!")
console.log("Resource Error Information: \n")
console.log('Resoruce ErrorID:' + resourceError.id + '\nURL:' + 
resourceError.url);
console.log('Resource Error Code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + 
'\nDescription: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
console.log("The Browser Replied:" + msg);
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
page.onLoadStarted = function(){
console.log("Loadng Page...")

};

page.onLoadFinished = function(){
console.log("Loading finished:\n");
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

page.viewportSize = {
width: 1920,
height: 1200
};

var sel = 'button1'; //DOM manipulate, selector
var type = 'click', //action

//webpage.open
page.open(url,function(status){
if(status === "success"){
page.includeJs( 
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js",function() 
{//jquery syntax has been successfully included
setTimeout(function(){
var t = page.evaluate(function(sel) {

var a = $('title').text();
return a;
},0,sel);
console.log("Title: " + t + "\n\n");

phantom.addCookie({
Cisco_DeviceManager     : 'value',   /* required property */
SSLPreference  : 2,  /* required property */
gettingstarted   : 1
});

page.open('http://10.44.39.252/xhome.htm', function (status) {
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("Your Document is Ready:"+ document.title +"\n");

/*ajax assynchronous http request
$.ajax({
async: false,//blocks the ajax call, SYNCHRONOUS ajax Request
url: 'http://10.44.39.252/setup_report.htm?button1=Continue', 
type: 'GET',
data: {button1: 'Continue'},
success: function (out) {
    console.log("REQUEST SENT!\n\n");
    console.log(typeof(out));
    $('button1').trigger(sel);
    console.log($('.homecontent').text);
    //$("button1").click(function(){
    // $("input").trigger("select");
    //});

},
error: function(){
console.log("Nein!");
}
});
*/


});
});
},3000);

setTimeout(function() {
page.render("phantomspecs1.jpg");
console.log("\nNow GTFO!")
phantom.exit();
},20000);

console.log("Wait for the Async...");//prints first!

},0);//closes includejs which doesnt operate in the next open...
}else{
    console.log("Connect fail");
    phantom.exit();
}
});
```

I need phantomJS to bypass the startup page and go to the CiscoDeviceManager where I can render the switch information. but my knowledge of JavaScript, JQuery and AJAX are still lacking (not natively a programmer but landed myself a coder job after college but I do have some basic concepts)

If any of you guys could help point me in the right direction for the next step I can finish the task and do documentation on it. No doubt would be valuable to the Phantom community.(Of which I am proud to be a part of)

Sincerely,
Afiq Abdul Hamid,
Cyberjaya Malaysia

Comment: PhatnomJS group version: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/qLz36fGuVdk

Answer (score 1):

As you're using a headless browser to do this work, the most logical approach is to use the headless browser *in the same way a normal user would*. Don't do crazy cookie manipulation and so on, it's just creating more work than you need to do.

PhantomJS is used to automate browser interactions using javascript, all you need to do is inject some simple javascript to interact with the UI.

The form that only displays once when a user logs in should be trivial to deal with.

After the user logs in, simply attempt to get the button element, if it exists, click on it.

```
var btn1 = document.querySelector('input[name="button1"]')
if(btn1 !== null) {
    //continue button exists trigger a click.
    btn1.click();
}
```

Also as you're doing scraping work, there's a fantastic library called [casperJS](http://casperjs.org/) that you can install on top of PhantomJS which abstracts away a lot of the complexity.

Comment: Great answer. Also, OP, be sure to use persistent cookies `--cookies-file=cookies.txt` so that splash page will be shown only once (if I understood your question correct)

Comment: Thank you Daniel Lane. I will focus on the button trigger approach for now. I tried implementing your code suggestion but the console returned 'button does not exist' 

I think I have to implement a waifor.js  or $.ajax inside the InjectJS({ and  page.evaluate({

Do you have any tips or should I ask it in a different question?

Yes I have considered Casper.js and I do have it installed but for now I will use phantom. Might move to casper later once this is finished.

Comment: Usually best to ask in another question. That said, If you know for sure it's loaded via ajax/dynamic javascript, you can perform a querySelector look up within a setInterval function (polling) until it finds the element.